# How to query rows with nearest column values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How should I construct T-SQL statement in order to achieve following:
from this

table1:

```
display_term|occurence

A|1

A|4

B|3

B|9
```

retrieve this

table2:

```
display_term|occurence

A|4

B|3
```

The "nearest distance" between A and B is 1 and it can be seen in resulting table.
i.e. I want to query the nearest (column "occurrence") distinct(column "display_term") records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will there only ever be two `term`s to worry about, or does it need to extend (somehow) to multiple terms?

Comment: why do you require the two points results to be in two rows not in the same row?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, it has to work for multiple terms as well.

Comment: Imagine that the values for A, B and C are, respectively, (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9). "Obviously", the best values for A and C are 3 and 7. What's not obvious is what the best value for B should be. That's why you need to carefully explain *how* this is meant to extend to multiple terms. (And this is a trivial example where the A and C values are obvious. For more complex examples, even that may not be so)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In the example you've given, the answer should be for A=3,B can be one of (4,5,6) and for C=7. This is because interval [3,7] is the shortest interval that covers all of A,B,C. So what I want is to find the shortest interval containing all the terms.

Comment: So, are you saying that, all we need to find is the two terms that are at the extremes of the range of all available values, minimize the gap between the values for those terms, and for all other terms pick arbitrary values, so long as they're between the two values selected? (And, can you see how far we're having to venture from you original question to try to form a decent spec for this?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are absolutely right! I'm sorry if I couldn't properly explain what I want, but you got the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just two terms, you can do something like:

```
declare @T table (display_term char(1) not null,occurence int not null)
insert into @T (display_term,occurence) values
('A',1),
('A',4),
('B',3),
('B',9)

select top 1
    *
from
    @T t1
        cross join
    @T t2
where
    t1.display_term = 'A' and
    t2.display_term = 'B'
order by ABS(t1.occurence - t2.occurence)
```

Which produces:

```
display_term occurence   display_term occurence
------------ ----------- ------------ -----------
A            4           B            3
```

(You can search for `UNPIVOT` based solutions if you need exactly the result set you asked for)

---

It's not clear from your question whether this needs to extend to more terms - there's no obvious way to re-interpret the requirement for more terms, so I've left that undone for now.

---

`UNPIVOT` based solution if exact result set required. Setup `@T` as above:

```
select display_term,occurence from (
select top 1
    t1.occurence as A,
    t2.occurence as B
from
    @T t1
        cross join
    @T t2
where
    t1.display_term = 'A' and
    t2.display_term = 'B'
order by ABS(t1.occurence - t2.occurence)
) t unpivot (occurence for display_term in (A,B)) as u
```

Result:

```
display_term                         occurence
------------------------------------ -----------
A                                    4
B                                    3
```

Comment: is there any way to extend your answer for a case with more than two terms assuming that I want a result set with corresponding number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

You said you want the nearest. It's not clear exactly what that means. Your example above shows the maximum of each display term. If you want the maximum value for each display term, you want to use aggregation. This is achieved by using the Group By and the Max method.

```
SELECT display_term, Max(occurence) as MaxOccurrence
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY display_term
```

Comment: I got your point. Sorry for not being clear. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

If a single row result will work for you, this will do it:

```
SELECT a.display_term AS adt,
       a.occurence As aoc,
       b.display_term AS bdt, 
       b.occurence AS boc,
       ABS(a.occurence - b.occurence) AS distance
FROM my_table a, my_table b
WHERE a.display_term = 'A'
  AND b.display_term = 'B'
  AND ABS(a.occurence - b.occurence) = (
    SELECT MIN(ABS(a.occurence - b.occurence))
    FROM my_table a, my_table b
    WHERE a.display_term = 'A'
      AND b.display_term = 'B'
  )
```